# Selecting max and min dates in a group by with null values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the max and min dates of users in my app from two different tables, but some users exist in one table and some the other, and some both.

Here is an example of my tables

```
Table A:
Id  Action        Date
1   A           2019-01-19
1   B           2019-02-19
2   A           2019-02-19
2   B           2019-03-19
3   A           2019-05-19
3   B           2019-06-19

Table B:
Id  Action      Date
1   A           2019-01-19
1   B           2019-02-19
2   A           2019-03-19
2   B           2019-04-19
4   A           2019-05-19
4   B           2019-06-19
```

Each table represents some action the user is performing and the date it occurs. They are distinct separate actions so there is no possibility of having them in 1 table. ID in this example is the user ID.

What is join both tables in user ids, and find the max and min dates for all actions. So in the example above, I would expect the result to be something like

```
Result:
Id   Min         Max         
1    2019-01-19  2019-02-19  
2    2019-02-19  2019-04-19
3    2019-05-19  2019-06-19
4    2019-05-19  2019-06-19
```

What I tried doing is something like:

```
SELECT A.Id, LEAST(min(A.Date), min(B.Date)), GREATEST(max(A.Date, B.Date))
FROM A
JOIN A.Id = B.Id
GROUP BY A.Id
```

but this is clearly not right because it groups by only users in table A, and will Users that only exist in table B. I started to play with full joins but was having issues with the group by statement because a user may not exist in either of the tables.

I am sure I am completely over complicating this, so please feel free to steer me in any direction that makes sense aside from restructuring the schema because the data has already been collected.

Here is SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74ce9f/9

Comment: I want to know what is the result of your query? If you have tried INNER JOIN?

Comment: Hey, Mark what you are trying to achieve is not possible in the given DB structure because if group by id of one table than other table's data may be missed. so if I can say that you use one table. And the problem (distinct separate actions) can be solved by using a new field type=(distinct actions) in the table.

Comment: I would start by fixing the structural problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try taking a union of both tables, followed by an aggregation by the `id`:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    MIN(Date) AS Min,
    MAX(Date) AS Max
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Date FROM A
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, Date FROM B
) t
GROUP BY Id;
```